# Open an image from asset folder in android

Tags: android

I need to get the images from asset folder by specifying the name of the image and set it to **Drawable**.

```
drw = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("/assets/images/"+drawables[i]),null);
```

But I get `File not found exception`.(images is subfolder of assets and drawables[i]- name of the image(say "ball.jpg").

Answer (score 0):

Write instead:

```
drw = Drawable.createFromStream(getAssets().open("images/"+drawables[i]),null);
```

file path should be:

```
"images/"+drawables[i]
```

when you write `getAssets()`  means open `assets` folder and find out path there.